# In Windows, download a file from the web to a remote server

Tags: ftp, remote-access, sftp

For example, there is a file www.domain.com/file.xyz
I do not want to download the file, then upload it to my server.
Is it possible to access the server, then tell it to get www.domain.com/file.xyz to a dir in the server? It the server runs on CentOS, and locally, I'm in windows.
Is that possible? If so how?

Answer (score 4):

SSH to the Centos server and use wget to download the file?

Depends on what access you have to the Centos server - if your access is limited you might be able to map a drive through windows (if the server has SMB configured), but behind the scenes this will still copy the file via your machine and then upload to the server which may not be what you want (for instance if you are on a low bandwidth link, but the server has plenty then you would want to download directly to the server)

Answer (score 2):

Jon is correct with wget. The following command will get your file for you directly from the web to the CentOS server:

```
wget http://www.domain.com/file.xyz
```

If you *don't* have wget installed and have permissions to install applications on the server:

```
yum install wget
```

Answer (score -1):

Map a drive to the target server and select it as the location for the download when prompted.

Comment: that still incurs the intermediate download location of the local machine